# Typo in remote name with Git; how do I fix?

Tags: git, github

Okay, I'm learning Git, so bear with me.
I'm trying to add my first repository to GitHub, using a command line (Windows PowerShell.)

I did the following, according these directions from a GitHub tutorial:

1. In your command line, navigate to your project directory. Type `git init` to initialize the directory as a Git repository.
2. Type `git remote add origin https://github.com/philosofool/github-upload.git`
3. Type `git add .`
4. Type `git commit -m "initializing repository"`
5. Type `git push -u origin master` to push the files you have locally to the remote on GitHub. (You may be asked to log in.)

Trying to be a good little learner, Iexit type everything out rather than just copy and paste. After about 40 minutes of trying to figure out why I'm getting a 443 Error I notice a typo: `git remote add origin https://githu.com/philosofool/github-upload.git` So, yeah, I assume the error is that I typed git*hu*.com not git*hub*.com.

Problem: When I re-enter all the stuff I used before, the typo persists. That is typing the `git remote add origin` with the correct URL doesn't get rid of the error: I'm still getting `fatal: unable to access 'https://githu.com/philosofool/github-upload.git/': Failed to connect to githu.com port 443: Timed out` with the typo in it. What do I do to start over?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+remote+url